# Draw to canvas right after it has been appended?

Tags: javascript, html

Can anyone explain why this won't draw a rect to the canvas? The canvas gets appended perfectly.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var width = $(window).width()
  var height = $(window).height() * 0.8

  var newCanvas = $('<canvas/>', {
    'class': 'cCanvas',
    id: 'myCanvas'
  }).prop({
    width: width,
    height: height
  });
  $('body').append(newCanvas);

  var c = $(".cCanvas")
  var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
  ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 150, 75);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can only get the context from the canvas as a raw HTML DOM element.

```js
$(function() {
  var width = $(window).width();
  var height = $(window).height() * 0.8;

  var newCanvas = $('<canvas>', {
    class: 'cCanvas',
    id: 'myCanvas'
  }).prop({
    width: width,
    height: height
  }).appendTo('body');

  var c = $(".cCanvas").get(0); // You need to get the raw element.
  var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
  ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 150, 75);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: why is that? has the canvas element not been converted yet from it's raw state? what is a raw DOM element?

Comment: I would go with @AlanSutherland, IMO to talk about "jQuery Objects" and "HTMLElements" is more clear than this "raw HTML DOM element"

Comment: Thanks alot. Gonna look this raw element up. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use

```
var c = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
```

I think its the best way, becouse when you use getEmelentById, it returns a HTML DOM Object. jQuery $('.cCanvas') return jQuery Object, so, additionally you need to specify the first element in object ( .get(0) or [0] ).